# What attachment do you need to plug the Apple EarPods that came with the iPhone 8 Plus into a Samsung Galaxy Note 20 Ultra (USB Type-C)?

Tags: iphone, usb, android

I have the Apple EarPods not AIRpods. I'm trying to find the attachment that would allow me to plug those directly into my Samsung Galaxy Note 20 Ultra which uses the Type C adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a **Lightning to USB Type-C** adapter, such as

- https://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F2CU070/

This adapter claims to work for connecting EarPods to a MacBook. It doesn’t mention your Samsung phone, but this is the necessary physical conversion required.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 8 Plus came with EarPods?  I thought Apple stopped doing that with the iPhone 7.  I'll answer this as a more general question on all models of EarPods to cover my bases.

There are two or three kinds of EarPods and the adapter you need depends on the kind of plug your EarPods have.  If you have the kind with the 1/8" round jack then you can use the Apple USB-C to 3.5 mm headphone jack adapter.
https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MU7E2AM/A/usb-c-to-35-mm-headphone-jack-adapter
The iPhone 8 has the Lightning jack for headphones and you may have the kind with the 1/8" jack and not know it as the Lightning adapter and EarPods mate together tightly and can look like one piece.  Look closely on if there is an adapter before buying anything.

(<*rant on*>It's one eighth of an inch, not 3.5 millimeters!  What's wrong with calling it by it's proper name, Apple?  I order my beer by the **pint**, not by 0.47 liters!  If we can keep that measurement for one product out of tradition then we can do it elsewhere!<*rant off*>)

If you have the kind with a flat Lightning jack then you could try a third party adapter to plug that in to USB-C.  I found one made by Anker.
https://www.bestbuy.com/site/anker-usb-c-to-lightning-female-audio-adapter-white/6413592.p
For the price of that adapter it may be cheaper to just buy the correct kind of earbuds or headphones.

I suspect Apple makes USB-C EarPods now to match their iPad Pro product line but I haven't seen any yet.  If so that should just work by plugging it in your Samsung phone.  If you tried that and it's not working then you just discovered why Apple continues to use the Lightning connector on their phones after most other phone makers moved on to USB-C.  Early USB-C headphones used a vendor specific wiring for analog audio over USB-C which were often not compatible with the USB-C standard wiring that came out a few years after USB-C was initially adopted.  This can mean many USB-C headphones and headphone adapters will not work with many phones.  This is another reason, besides the cost issue mentioned earlier, to just buy new earbuds than try to find an adapter.  An adapter will cost something like $10 to $30 for earbuds that run about $20.  Maybe a $10 adapter for some really nice earbuds makes sense but I'd think it foolish to buy a $30 adapter for earbuds when new earbuds can be had for the same price.